# making two routes on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a web app. which will have two languages on it.

I will have a default root page, root :to => "home#index" which will be on English (e.g www.test.com/en/home). Now, after clicking on other language on the page, for example russian, i would like to switch page from **www.test.com/en/home** to **www.test.com/ru/home** which will load different page on language i selected and it will automatically become a home page.

First idea was to create a controller for this, but since my rails knowlege is on lower level, i assume thats not something i would like to do.

Any suggestions?

-Michael

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the i18n Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

I excepted that you want multi language app, so your routes.rb may look like this bellow:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope ':locale' do
    root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Better informations you can find on [2.5 Setting the Locale from the URL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale)

Comment: yea, but what about /en/home or /ru/home pages? how to make url look like www.test.com/en|ru/home ?

Comment: If you want use one locale (en) for more than one url( en/.., ru/..), then edit method set_locale and add this line on end `I18n.locale = 'en' if ['ru'].include?(I18n.locale)`

Comment: aha okay. do i have to create a new pages for /en/ and /ru/ or it will be created automatically?

Comment: please read whole article http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html, and  you can find the answer in part **3.5 Localized Views**.

Comment: it actually pass a locale='xx' param, localhost:3000/?locale=es, when you defined your translate in your i18n files you can generate helpers for graving the current language(for example if the current user have language select change that) or like you mentioned with a click in language, you go to the same root_path but with the param